# Cocoapods installation failed, Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

Cocoapods installation failed,

---

Version:

macOS Catalina `10.15.4`

ruby `2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]`

Homebrew `2.2.6`

gem `3.1.2`

```
gem sources -l

*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
https://gems.ruby-china.com
```

---

```
sudo gem install cocoapod
```

or

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

---

Error result：

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200409-15528-unemw5.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in`block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in`try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in`block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in`open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in`open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in`checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:10:in`system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:34:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.12.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out

If you solve this problem？

Comment: Try [researching the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Error+installing+cocoapods+failed+to+build+native+gem).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I fixed it by running

```
brew install cocoapods
```

And
You may want to remove it:

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/pod'
```

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Install homebrew if you haven't already. https://brew.sh/

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on Catalina 10.15.7 & ruby 2.6

Comment: After above commands, we need to perform pod setup or what

Comment: pod is installed, you can pod init, pod install ...

Comment: Even works for Big Sur mac OS

Answer (score 1):

Try adding --disable-system-libffi to the gem install command.

This worked for me:

`gem inst cocoapods -- --disable-system-libffi`

Answer (score 1):

These lines of code can help to install any pods to your project on a Macbook M1.

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod install
```